# Not able to execute lifecycle operation using script plugin

Tags: cloudify

I'm trying to learn how to use script plugin. I'm following script plugin docs [here](https://docs.cloudify.co/4.6/working_with/official_plugins/script/) but not able to make it work.

I've tried to use the plugin in two ways. The first, when cloudify.interface.lifecycle.start operation is mapped directly to a script:

```
tosca_definitions_version: cloudify_dsl_1_3
imports:
  - 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/4.5.5/types.yaml'
node_templates:
  Import_Project:
    type: cloudify.nodes.WebServer
    capabilities:
      scalable:
        properties:
          default_instances: 1
    interfaces:
      cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle:
        start:
          implementation: scripts/create_project.sh
          inputs: {}
```

The second with a direct mapping:

```
tosca_definitions_version: cloudify_dsl_1_3
imports:
  - 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/4.5.5/types.yaml'
node_templates:
  Import_Project:
    type: cloudify.nodes.WebServer
    capabilities:
      scalable:
        properties:
          default_instances: 1
    interfaces:
      cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle:
        start:
          implementation: script.script_runner.tasks.run
          inputs:
            script_path: scripts/create_project.sh
```

I've created a directory named scripts and placed the below create_project.sh script in this directory:

```
#! /bin/bash -e

ctx logger info "Hello to this world"
hostname
```

I'm getting errors while validating the blueprint.
Error when operation is mapped directly to a script:

```
[2019-04-13 13:29:40.594] [DEBUG] DslParserExecClient - got output from dsl parser Could not extract plugin from operation mapping 'scripts/create_project.sh', which is declared for operation 'start'. In interface 'cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle' in node 'Import_Project' of type 'cloudify.nodes.WebServer'
  in: /opt/cloudify-composer/backend/dev/workspace/2/tmp-27O0e1t813N6as
  in line: 3, column: 2
  path: node_templates.Import_Project
  value: {'interfaces': {'cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle': {'start': {'implementation': 'scripts/create_project.sh', 'inputs': {}}}}, 'type': 'cloudify.nodes.WebServer', 'capabilities': {'scalable': {'properties': {'default_instances': 1}}}}
```

Error when using a direct mapping:

```
[2019-04-13 13:25:21.015] [DEBUG] DslParserExecClient - got output from dsl parser node 'Import_Project' has no relationship which makes it contained within a host and it has a plugin 'script' with 'host_agent' as an executor. These types of plugins must be installed on a host
  in: /opt/cloudify-composer/backend/dev/workspace/2/tmp-279QCz2CV3Y81L
  in line: 2, column: 0
  path: node_templates
  value: {'Import_Project': {'interfaces': {'cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle': {'start': {'implementation': 'script.script_runner.tasks.run', 'inputs': {'script_path': 'scripts/create_project.sh'}}}}, 'type': 'cloudify.nodes.WebServer', 'capabilities': {'scalable': {'properties': {'default_instances': 1}}}}}
```

What is missing to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I also found the Cloudify Script Plugin examples from their documentation do not work: https://docs.cloudify.co/4.6/working_with/official_plugins/configuration/script/

However, I found I can make the examples work by adding an **executor** line in parallel with the implementation line to override the host_agent executor as follows:

```
tosca_definitions_version: cloudify_dsl_1_3
imports:
  - 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/4.5.5/types.yaml'
node_templates:
  Import_Project:
    type: cloudify.nodes.WebServer
    capabilities:
      scalable:
        properties:
          default_instances: 1
    interfaces:
      cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle:
        start:
          implementation: scripts/create_project.sh
          executor: central_deployment_agent
          inputs: {}
```